# javascript and jshint, undefined

Tags: javascript, jshint, defined

Today I wrote this code:

```
(function (window) {
    'use strict';

    function ViewPort() {
        var getSize = function () {
                var e = window,
                    a = 'inner';

                if (!('innerWidth' in window)) {
                    a = 'client';
                    e = Document.documentElement || Document.body;
                }
                return { width : e[a + 'Width'], height : e[a + 'Height'] };
            },

            update = function () {
                var vw = (getSize().width / 100);

                Document.querySelector('html').style.fontSize = vw + 'px';
            };

        Document.addEventListener("resize", update());
    }

    function run() {
        return new ViewPort();
    }

    window.viewport = run;
}(window));

window.onload = function () {
    'use strict';
    viewport();
};
```

When I use jshint then I got errors like this:

```
11  'Document' is not defined. (W117)   e = Document.documentElement || Document.body;
19  'Document' is not defined. (W117)   Document.querySelector('html').style.fontSize = vw + 'px';
22  'Document' is not defined. (W117)   Document.addEventListener("resize", update());
30  'window' is not defined. (W117) }(window));
32  'window' is not defined. (W117) window.onload = function () {
34  'viewport' is not defined. (W117)   viewport();
```

any one can help me fix my errors? I dont have any idea how to fix it, This code I have in scripts.js file not inline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive. `document` is all lowercase. It should work, then.

If that still doesn't work, you could try adding a directive to the start of your file to imply that the script is meant for the browser, and the browser globals are available.

Add this comment to the top of your script:

```
/* jshint browser: true */
```

Comment: ok this help me and fix document problem but why viewport() is undefined?

Comment: Where does the viewport function come from? Is that PhantomJS?

Comment: its here window.viewport = run;
}(window));

Comment: Try using window.viewport if you define it as such. But I'm really just guessing at this point.